# Check for Date Between Dates w/ SQL

Tags: sql, between

I'm getting an error when running this query:

```
SELECT '06/30/' + 
 CASE WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN Cast('1/01/' + YEAR(GETDATE()) + ' 12:01:01' As DateTime) And Cast('6/30/' + YEAR(GETDATE()) + ' 12:01:01' as DateTime)
      THEN CAST(
           YEAR(DATEADD(YY, 2, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4))
      WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN Cast('7/01/' + YEAR(GETDATE()) + ' 12:01:01' As DateTime) And Cast('12/31/' + YEAR(GETDATE()) + ' 12:01:01' as DateTime)
      THEN CAST(
           YEAR(DATEADD(YY, 3, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4))
      END
      AS DateEnding FOR XML RAW
```

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1/01/' to data type int.`

Comment: What error? Post it please.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1/01/' to data type int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to CAST or CONVERT your `YEAR(GETDATE())` to varchar(4) when trying to combine it with text, otherwise, it attempts to convert the text to an int instead.

```
SELECT '06/30/' + 
 CASE WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN Cast('1/01/' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' 12:01:01' As DateTime) And Cast('6/30/' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' 12:01:01' as DateTime)
      THEN CAST(
           YEAR(DATEADD(YY, 2, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4))
      WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN Cast('7/01/' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' 12:01:01' As DateTime) And Cast('12/31/' + CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ' 12:01:01' as DateTime)
      THEN CAST(
           YEAR(DATEADD(YY, 3, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4))
      END
      AS DateEnding FOR XML RAW
```

Answer (score 0):

JamieSee is correct about casting it to VARCHAR(4). A better way would be to format using non-ambiguous dates. SQL will always work out 6/30/2012 as 30th June 2012, but is 1/7/2012 the 1st July (US Format) or 7th Jan (UK Format)?

```
SELECT '06/30/' + 
 CASE WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN Cast(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-01-01 12:01:01' As DateTime) And Cast(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-06-30 12:01:01' as DateTime)
      THEN CAST(
           YEAR(DATEADD(YY, 2, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4))
      WHEN GETDATE() BETWEEN Cast(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-07-01 12:01:01' As DateTime) And Cast(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-12-31 12:01:01' as DateTime)
      THEN CAST(
           YEAR(DATEADD(YY, 3, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR(4))
      END
      AS DateEnding FOR XML RAW
```